# I had to create each of the main directories and now they are all showing on my desktop

Tags: 20.04, directory

Whenever I tried to access a directory such as `Downloads` or `Documents`, a dialog showed up  with the next error message:

```
"Oops! Something went wrong."
Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.
```

After searching for a while, I got myself reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179483/linux-cannot-find-documents-directory) question, but nothing worked. My final "solution" was to open up my terminal, go to `~` and create each directory by running:

```
mkdir Music Pictures Videos Documents Public Templates Downloads Desktop
```

Now I can access those directories, but there is a folder icon for each one of those on my desktop. It seems wrong to me. Is there something wrong with what I did?

I'm using `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `ls -l ~/Desktop` and also `ls -l ~/`.

Comment: A reset did the job, now I don't have any icon on my desktop. Weird but works for me!